# Attached entities not being updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to update an entity which but when I call save changes nothing happens. Here's the code how I attached the entity. I am using EF6.1 and MVC5.1 by the way

```
var entity = db.Entity.Attach(existingEntity);
entity = new Entity(args0, args1, args2)
entity.Id = existingEntity.Id;
db.SaveChanges()
```

Here's the entity class:

```
 public class Entity : Entity
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PropertyA { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; private set; }
 }

 public Entity(string args0, string args1, string args2)
 {
      this.PropertyA = args0;
      this.PropertyB = args1;
      this.PropertyC = args2;
 }
```

Note that I did set the properties setter to private as I have some inner workings within the class. I'm thinking that the reason why EF can't update the entity is because I instantiate a new one though I did set its primary key. I did also try changing the State to Modified but it just running the "update script" but it doesn't really reflect the changes I made on each property

Any possible resolution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I am myself new to MVC and EF. But here goes.

Are you not mixing up your DAL and BLL by using private set?

Also, when you already have the existing entity why cant you just update the properties for entity directly? The way your class has been set up it can only be created, not modified.

Lastly, I think you have to explicitly tell EF that existingEntity has been modified.

Comment: Well as far as I read my code no I am not mixing the two. You are right the class was constructed only for creation which I think is my mistake. I did that because there are some sort of calculations with the properties and need some parameters outside the class plus since I need it to have auto-computed (with params)

Answer (score 0):

```
var entity = new Entity(args0, args1, args2)
entity.Id = existingEntity.Id;
db.Entity.Attach(entity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Could you give a description?

Comment: that would throw an exception saying cannot more than track 2 same object keys and I believe when you attach an entity its state is Unmodified